# C# Multithreading with slots

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this function which checks for proxy servers and currently it checks only a number of threads and waits for all to finish until the next set is starting. Is it possible to start a new thread as soon as one is finished from the maximum allowed?

```
for (int i = 0; i < listProxies.Count(); i+=nThreadsNum)
{                              
    for (nCurrentThread = 0; nCurrentThread < nThreadsNum; nCurrentThread++)
    {
        if (nCurrentThread < nThreadsNum)
        {
           string strProxyIP = listProxies[i + nCurrentThread].sIPAddress;
           int nPort = listProxies[i + nCurrentThread].nPort;
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew<ProxyAddress>(() => CheckProxyServer(strProxyIP, nPort, nCurrentThread)));
        }
     }                

     Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

     foreach (var tsk in tasks)
     {
        ProxyAddress result = tsk.Result;
        UpdateProxyDBRecord(result.sIPAddress, result.bOnlineStatus);
     }

     tasks.Clear();                
}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/chaining-tasks-by-using-continuation-tasks) what you're looking for?

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for a ThreadPool: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?view=netframework-4.8 or Parallel.ForEach: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @EJoshuaS not really, because continuation tasks/chains continue with the results from it's parent, I don't need to pass results from one thread to another

Comment: You are not using Tasks correctly. "Checking proxies" is I/O bound. Chances are you don't need more than 1 thread to drive all of them concurrently. You don't need multi-threading or the accepted answer using the Task Parallel Library (which is meant for CPU bound operations). Don't do Task.Result, read up on [async best practices](https://github.com/davidfowl/AspNetCoreDiagnosticScenarios/blob/master/AsyncGuidance.md) and go with one of the options in [BionicCode's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57681685/68080) which are superior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems much more simple:

```
int numberProcessed = 0;
Parallel.ForEach(listProxies,
  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = nThreadsNum },
  (p)=> {
    var result = CheckProxyServer(p.sIPAddress, s.nPort, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    UpdateProxyDBRecord(result.sIPAddress, result.bOnlineStatus);
    Interlocked.Increment(numberProcessed);
});
```

With slots:

```
var obj = new Object();
var slots = new List<int>();
Parallel.ForEach(listProxies,
  new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = nThreadsNum },
  (p)=> {
    int threadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
    int slot = slots.IndexOf(threadId);
    if (slot == -1)
    {
      lock(obj)
      {
        slots.Add(threadId);
      }
      slot = slots.IndexOf(threadId);
    }
    var result = CheckProxyServer(p.sIPAddress, s.nPort, slot);
    UpdateProxyDBRecord(result.sIPAddress, result.bOnlineStatus);
});
```

I took a few shortcuts there to guarantee thread safety.  You don't have to do the normal check-lock-check dance because there will never be two threads attempting to add the same threadid to the list, so the second check will always fail and isn't needed.  Secondly, for the same reason, I don't believe you need to ever lock around the outer IndexOf either.  That makes this a very highly efficient concurrent routine that rarely locks (it should only lock nThreadsNum times) no matter how many items are in the enumerable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198564/discussion-on-answer-by-robert-mckee-c-multithreading-with-slots).

Comment: You can simplify the code with:
int slot = (int)Task.CurrentId;
slot will have a value between 1 and nThreadsNum

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim?view=netframework-4.8#examples) or the Producer-Consumer Pattern using a [`BlockinCollection<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1?view=netframework-4.8). Both solution support cancellation.

**SemaphoreSlim**

```
private async Task CheckProxyServerAsync(IEnumerable<object> proxies)
{
  var tasks = new List<Task>();
  int currentThreadNumber = 0;
  int maxNumberOfThreads = 8;

  using (semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxNumberOfThreads, maxNumberOfThreads))
  {
    foreach (var proxy in proxies)
    {
      // Asynchronously wait until thread is available if thread limit reached
      await semaphore.WaitAsync();

      string proxyIP = proxy.IPAddress;
      int port = proxy.Port;
      tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => CheckProxyServer(proxyIP, port, Interlocked.Increment(ref currentThreadNumber)))
        .ContinueWith(
          (task) =>
          {
            ProxyAddress result = task.Result;

            // Method call must be thread-safe!
            UpdateProxyDbRecord(result.IPAddress, result.OnlineStatus);

            Interlocked.Decrement(ref currentThreadNumber);

            // Allow to start next thread if thread limit was reached
            semaphore.Release();
          },
          TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion));
    }

    // Asynchronously wait until all tasks are completed
    // to prevent premature disposal of semaphore
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
  }
}
```

---

**Producer-Consumer Pattern**

```
// Uses a fixed number of same threads
private async Task CheckProxyServerAsync(IEnumerable<ProxyInfo> proxies)
{
  var pipe = new BlockingCollection<ProxyInfo>();
  int maxNumberOfThreads = 8;
  var tasks = new List<Task>();

  // Create all threads (count == maxNumberOfThreads)
  for (int currentThreadNumber = 0; currentThreadNumber < maxNumberOfThreads; currentThreadNumber++)
  {
    tasks.Add(
      Task.Run(() => ConsumeProxyInfo(pipe, currentThreadNumber)));
  }

  proxies.ToList().ForEach(pipe.Add);
  pipe.CompleteAdding();

  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private void ConsumeProxyInfo(BlockingCollection<ProxyInfo> proxiesPipe, int currentThreadNumber)
{
  while (!proxiesPipe.IsCompleted)
  {
    if (proxiesPipe.TryTake(out ProxyInfo proxy))
    {
      int port = proxy.Port;
      string proxyIP = proxy.IPAddress;
      ProxyAddress result = CheckProxyServer(proxyIP, port, currentThreadNumber); 

      // Method call must be thread-safe!
      UpdateProxyDbRecord(result.IPAddress, result.OnlineStatus);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a nice solution and a good use of SemaphoreSlim once you fix nCurrentThread.

Comment: @RobertMcKee What needs a fix, can you tell me  please? I think `nCurrentThread` is just the thread counter right? I mean total thread count or relative to available threads (does it need to be decremented too)?

Comment: He was using it as a thread index, so it should range from 0 to the maximum number of threads, so each currently running thread would have a unique value between that range.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thank you for the hint. I changed it.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question properly, this is actually fairly simple to do with `await Task.WhenAny`. Basically, you keep a collection of all of the running tasks. Once you reach a certain number of tasks running, you wait for one or more of your tasks to finish, and then you remove the tasks that were completed from your collection and continue to add more tasks.

Here's an example of what I mean below:

```
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            // I want my list of tasks to contain at most 5 tasks at once
            if (tasks.Count == 5)
            {
                // Wait for at least one of the tasks to complete
                await Task.WhenAny(tasks.ToArray());

                // Remove all of the completed tasks from the list
                tasks = tasks.Where(t => !t.IsCompleted).ToList();
            }

            // Add some task to the list
            tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(async delegate ()
                {
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }));
        }
```

Comment: @MarioM Before you remove the tasks from the list, you can do a LINQ query for the completed ones and get their result.

Comment: Is it possible to have a slot id? so each thread knows which number of the thread is having? so I can display progress status for each thread in a grid

Comment: @MarioM Could you use the index in the list?

Comment: no, because the index is going up to 5000 and I have only 32 threads

Comment: Also I cannot add the parameters to the function with async delegate 
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew<ProxyAddress>(async delegate () => CheckProxyServer(strProxyIP, nPort, nCurrentThread)));

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing your approach slightly. Instead of starting and stopping threads, put your proxy server data in a concurrent queue, one item for each proxy server. Then create a *fixed number of threads* (or async tasks) to work on the queue. This is more likely to provide smooth performance (you aren't starting and stopping threads over and over, which has overhead) and is a lot easier to code, in my opinion.

A simple example:

```
class ProxyChecker
{
    private ConcurrentQueue<ProxyInfo> _masterQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<ProxyInfo>();

    public ProxyChecker(IEnumerable<ProxyInfo> listProxies)
    {
        foreach (var proxy in listProxies)
        {
            _masterQueue.Enqueue(proxy);
        }
    }

    public async Task RunChecks(int maximumConcurrency)
    {
        var count = Math.Max(maximumConcurrency, _masterQueue.Count);
        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select( i => WorkerTask() ).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task WorkerTask()
    {
        ProxyInfo proxyInfo;
        while ( _masterList.TryDequeue(out proxyInfo))
        {
            DoTheTest(proxyInfo.IP, proxyInfo.Port)
        }
    }
}
```